# Rails 4: devise custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I want to have a "Account Settings" page, which is for editing name and password, and a "Profile Edit" page, which is for updating profile picture and personal information. The default devise path for user edit is '/edit', but I want to make it '/users/:id/account'. I also want to make the profile edit page have the path '/users/:id/edit_profile'. Following the instructions on the devise wiki, I was able to change the sign up and sign in paths, but it doesn't seem to work for other ones.

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :user, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "signin", :sign_up => "signup", :edit => "profile" }
resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
resources :projects
root 'static_pages#home'
match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get'
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

rake routes

```
        new_user_session GET    /signin(.:format)            devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /signin(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /sign_out(.:format)          devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)      devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)     devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)            devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /                            devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /signup(.:format)            devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)              devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /                            devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /                            devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /                            devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
                projects GET    /projects(.:format)          projects#index
                         POST   /projects(.:format)          projects#create
             new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
            edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
                 project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
                         PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
                         PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
                         DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
                    root GET    /                            static_pages#home
                    help GET    /help(.:format)              static_pages#help
                   about GET    /about(.:format)             static_pages#about
                 contact GET    /contact(.:format)           static_pages#contact
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **I want to make it '/users/:id/account'**

Why don't you do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path_names: { edit: "account" } do
   get :edit_profile #-> I presume you have an "edit_profile" controller action?
end
```

This will give you the following routes:

```
domain.com/users/:id/account #-> edit
domain.com/users/:id/edit_profile #-> edit_profile
```

--

The [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes) suggests you cannot edit the `user` object with `Devise` directly - it's more for defining the `authentication` system of the system.